# Do style attributes contribute to the 50k css limit

Tags: amp-html

In an amp page, I know there is a 50k limit that is allowed for css (between style tags in the head).  I'm wondering if inline style *attributes* contribute to the size as well?

I can't find this in the docs anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum size

It is a validation error if the author stylesheet or inline styles together are larger than 75,000 bytes. [For more infomation click here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#maximum-size)

**Note :** Each instance of an inline style has a 1,000 byte limit.

Comment: so you mean inline-style counted as well as amp-custom css?  @Bachcha Singh

Comment: Yes and now limit is increase to 75k

Comment: are you sure? because i have same thought with the person who come out with this question , i guess inline style is an exception, and i wantto  makesure is there a state for that? thanks in advance @Bachcha Singh

Comment: Yes,  It is a validation error if the author stylesheet or inline styles together are larger than 75,000 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro @Bachcha Singh

Comment: My pleasure, one more thing,  Each instance of an inline style has a 1,000 byte limit.

Answer (score 0):

It was stated in the [documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/validation-workflow/validation_errors?format=websites#style-and-layout-errors) that:

> The AMP validator throws this error when it measures the size of the
> **styles content within `<style amp-custom>`** to exceed the 75,000 bytes
> limit.